# How to use lucene with javascript

Tags: javascript, lucene

I have dozens of static web pages on an intranet. I would like to enable search capability to these static pages via javascript. I will have the lucene index in the same directory as my javascript files. That being said is there a way to use lucene with javascript?

Answer (score 1):

Just having index files will get you nowhere, Lucene requires Java to use those files to produce something meaningful.

The best you can do is index those pages in [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) and fire a Javascript search request to Solr.